# How to use multiples objects in a function on R

Tags: r, function, assign

I'm completely new in programing so as i'm in R.
I have multiples objects with similar names (ams.1,ams.2,ams.3, etc) and i would like to run a function (it's the function "crop" from a package) with them and then assign new objects (data.final.1, data.final.2) to the result. Just like that:

```
for(x in 1:119) {
 assign(paste("data.final", x, sep = "."),crop(a,ams.(x)))
}
```

Apparently this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It is better to keep the datasets in a `list` and you don't need to create new objects in the global environment Try `lapply(mget(paste0('ams.', 1:119)), function(x) crop(a, x))` (not tested)